# Show that $f_{xy}(0,0)=1$ and $f_{yx}(0,0)=-1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

[image]

I'm not quite sure how to approach the problem. I tried to approach the limit along the $x$ axis and the $y$ axis but I keep getting $0$. I've done the partial derivatives as well but I don't see how that helps me. Could you give me a hint on how to start it? I think I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please type up the question using MathJax. This helps the question be more searchable.

Comment: If you've computed the partial derivatives, can you include them here?

Comment: What do you get for the derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$?

Comment: I don't know how to add photos in the comments so I've edited the post. These are the derivatives I've got

Answer (score 0):

for your control $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{y \left(x^4+4 x^2
   y^2-y^4\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$
and $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{x \left(x^4-4 x^2
   y^2-y^4\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$

Comment: ok, let me try to figure it out a bit.:)

Comment: then good luck!

Comment: I'll come back to you if i can't figure it out. Thank you!:)

Comment: ok i'm waiting for you to you will come back!

Comment: i meant i'm waiting for you until you will come back!

Comment: ok, I've tried to figure out away of giving common factor and simplifying but didn't really work:(

Comment: ok should i send you the second derivative for your Control?

Comment: Yes. That'd be great!